# Is there a way to use native iOS controls in OpenGL

Tags: ios, opengl-es, input

I have my OpenGL C++ game and i want to provide some text input. Right now i considered and implemented two options:

1) Using wrapper for native input field. This looks-and-feels great, but does't respect my internal structure - it is always on top of my application. If some element is overlapping this input (ie.: confirmation dialog) it still drawing above my whole application window.

2) Using hack with 0-sized input field and transmitting it's input into game, and drawing all text by myself. This works good, but it's only supports basic input-backspace operation. No "zoom", no "drag cursor to position", no "copy-paste-select_all".

So i wonder - as i understand all native controls are implemented using OpenGL. So is there a method to "draw" them manualy? If so, i could have placed them in my display list and problem with overlapping will be gone.

Comment: I believe manually drawing them will be a dead end.. You can create textures from UIView and then display it in GL but it does not solve the control problem (a button wouldn't be pressable). Then there is always cocos2d or something similar..